# Prove that if $deg(u)+deg(v) \geq n-1$ for every two non adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ of $G$ then $G$ is connected and $diam(G) \leq 2$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$. Prove that if $deg(u)+deg(v) \geq n-1$ for every two non adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$  of $G$ then $G$ is connected and $diam(G) \leq 2$

This is what I got so far

Let $u$ and $v$ be 2 non adjacent vertices in $G$. Since $G$ has order $n$

$$deg(u) \leq n-2$$

and

$$deg(v) \leq n-2$$

so

$$deg(u) +deg(v) \leq 2(n-1)$$

thus

$$n-1 \leq deg(u)+deg(v) \leq 2(n-1)$$

now I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $G$ is a graph of order $n\geq 2$ such that $\delta(G) \geq \frac{1}{2}(n-1),$ then any two non-adjacent vertices in $G$ have a common neighbour.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412577/if-g-is-a-graph-of-order-n-geq-2-such-that-deltag-geq-frac12n-1)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213428/prove-a-graph-is-connected-if-degx-degy-geq-n-1?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: prove that $u$ and $v$ have a common neighbour.

Detailed hint: Assume $u$ and $v$ have no common neighbour. Let $N(x)$ be the set of neighbours of $x$. Then $|N(u)\cup N(v)|=deg(u)+deg(v)$. But what is the maximal $N(u)\cup N(v)$?

Comment: can you explain it a little bit further please? I still don't know how to prove that $u$ and $v$ have a common adjacent vertex

Comment: if not, then their neighbours partition a subset of $G\setminus\{u,v\}$. How big can the sum of their degrees be in this case?

Comment: their degree? what is their? the neighbors or $u$ and $v$?

Comment: $deg(u)+deg(v)$. I detailed the hint in the answer.

Comment: ok, so if they don't have any common neighbor then $deg (u) \leq n-2-deg(v)$ so $deg(u)+deg(v) <n-1$ which is a contradiction, so they must have some common neighbor. Am I correct?

Comment: yes that's it !

Comment: @Denis Why deg(u)≤n−2−deg(v) ? how can I conclude that ?

Comment: @hemi if we call $N(u)$ the neighbours of u, under the assumption that u and v have no common neighbours we get $N(u)\subseteq G\setminus (\{u,v\}\cup N(v))$ hence the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ and $v$ be non-adjacent vertices of $G$. Assume that $N(u) \cup N(v) = \emptyset$. Then $deg(u)+deg(v) \leqslant n-2$. Contradiction with $deg(u)+deg(v) \geqslant n-1$. Hence $N(u) \cup N(v) \neq \emptyset$. Thus $d_G(u,v) \leqslant 2$ for all $u$ and $v$ of $G$ and finnaly $\textrm{diam}(G) \leqslant 2$.