# Prove a graph is connected if $\deg(x) + \deg(y) \geq n-1$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

One of my workshop questions in preparation for my exams is:

### For any non-adjacent nodes $x,y$ on a simple graph G on $n$ vertices. We have $\deg(x) + \deg(y) \geq n-1$ Prove that G is connected.

Now I understand what the question is asking however during trying to think about how it works, I found that in a connected graph: take graph 9 From the picture below, if the bottom $2$ nodes are $x$ and $y$, but we made it a 5 node disconnected graph. Then we have $\deg(x) + \deg(y) = 2 + 2 = 4 = 5-1 = 4$ so the equation holds, but the graph is disconnected. I'm unsure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated thank you. 
[image]

Comment: Say that your new node (the fifth node) is $z$. Then $\deg(x) + \deg(z) = 2 < 4$. The inequality should hold for any pair of non-adjacent nodes.

Comment: @JaneDoé Ah that makes a lot more sense Thanks a lot, i should've seen that sorry

Comment: Prove the contrapositive. Assume that $A,B$ are two different connected components of $G$. Take $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. Then the degree of $x$ is not more than $|A|-1$ and the degree of $y$ is not more than $|B|-1$. Therefore, $\deg(x)+\deg(y)\leq |A|-1+|B|-1=|A\cup B|-2\leq|G|-2$, where the equation $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|$ follows due to $A$ and $B$ being disjoint.

Comment: @logarithm That is full answer so you should post it as that, not as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer given by **logarithm** in comments:

Prove the contrapositive. Assume that A,B are two different connected components of G. Take $x\in A$ and $y\in B$. Then the degree of x is not more than |A|-1 and the degree of y is not more than $|B|-1$. Therefore, $$\deg(x)+\deg(y)\leq |A|-1+|B|-1=|A\cup B|-2\leq|G|-2,$$ where the equation $|A|+|B|=|A\cup B|$ follows due to A and B being disjoint.